# Does the enemy see Hanzo's sonar?

Tags: overwatch

It didn't occur to me during the open beta, tried to look around me recently couldn't see the red Hanzo's sonar.

So can my team see the other team's Hanzo's sonic arrow on the ground/wall near me?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by see Hanzo's sonic arrow? the actual arrow, or who is revealed by it?

Comment: The physical arrow on the ground/wall.

Comment: @Dragonrage I think he's asking if they can see the aura emitted from it, thus notifying them they are being tracked, and can they know they are being tracked.

Comment: Either the Aura or the stick works .... I'd figure out if I'm visible either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on personal experience, when playing against a Hanzo you can see them fire a sonic arrow and see the aura emitted from it when it initially lands, however the aura is not persistent, and the sonic arrows don't look much different than his other arrows nor do they stay for very long. So looking for the sonic arrow on the ground doesn't really help you know if you are being tracked or not, and unless you see him shoot it, you probably aren't going to be able to tell where it is.