# How can I tell if an enemy team has wallhacks on?

Tags: overwatch

Is there any way to tell when the enemy team has wallhacks on, either in the form of Widowmaker's Recon Sensor, or Hanzo's Sonar?

I'm mostly curious if there are any other ways to tell when an enemy Widowmaker has her ult active besides the voice line "*No one can hide from my sight*", perhaps visually?

Comment: if you die immediately as you walk around a corner, thats a pretty good sign, as for Hanzo, see this http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266782/does-the-enemy-see-hanzos-sonar

Comment: @Dragonrage I mean, it'd be a good idea to know if they have hacks on without dying rather than dying so you can tell your team "Crap, they have wallhacks on"

Comment: I dont think the term wallhacks really fits this though. wallhacks are actual hacks, not an ability that grants vision.

Comment: @Dragonrage Wallhacks are the de facto callout for Widow's ability for mos t competitive teams and matches I've spectated. And it doesn't change the fact that her ult is literally a wallhack; it tracks enemies and where they are moving

Comment: that is highly misleading and confusing, as its not a hack. it should be called infrared sight or something.

Comment: @Dragonrage Just as Mcree's ult is called Dead Eye, yet many players refer to it as "High Noon"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40298/discussion-between-o-o-and-dragonrage).

Comment: The question says "curious if there are any other ways to tell when an enemy Widowmaker has her ult active besides the voice line." This seems to invalidate Danmaku's answer.

Your comment says "without dying rather than dying so you can tell your team 'Crap, they have wallhacks on'" This invalidated my now-deleted answer. I don't think there is an acceptable answer beyond those two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Hanzo's wallhack is answered in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266782/does-the-enemy-see-hanzos-sonar). As for Widowmaker, it is possible to hear her say "Personne n'échappe à mon regard", which is French for "No one can hide from my sight", but it's very quiet compared to other ultimates like Barrage, Tactical Visor, or Rip-Tire.

Comment: I disagree, its loud enough, if you are playing with headphones on you will hear her activate her visor. Also she says it in English in my games.

Comment: I don't think you can disagree it's more quiet than pretty much every other ultimate in the game.

Comment: Is there any way to tell if she has wallhacks on even after she's said the voice line? Usually it's someone in my squad who hears her saying the voice line then letting everyone else know that she's got hacks on, but sometimes we've all been downed and unaware that she's activated hacks

Comment: Not until you get shot right after rounding a corner, I'm afraid.

Comment: Overwatch rebalances sounds on the fly depending on whats going on.  It prioritizes the sounds based on whats currently threatening you.  If not much is going on then a Widowmaker might sound fairly loud, but if there's a Genji right on top of you then it'll quiet the Widowmaker and make the Genji louder

Comment: No, it depends on whether she's on your team or the enemy team. Like every other character.

Comment: @ИвоНедев: She says it in English, loud enough for you to hear, because that's your teammate.  Every ult has two different voice lines depending on whether it is friendly or hostile.  Widowmaker's hostile line is in French, following the standard of English-friendly/non-English-hostile that several other heroes use (e.g. Mercy, Hanzo).